# How to find the impact of one variable on the other when there seems to no correlation between them?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, data-science, artificial-intelligence, non-linear-regression

can we predict growth percentage in sales of an item given the change in discount(positive or negative number) from the previous year as a predictor variable. There seems to be no correlation between these. How to solve this problem using machine learning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the wrong track to ask this question.

Correlation is on the knowledge side of Statistics, Please check **Pearson’s correlation of coefficient / Spearman’s correlation of coefficient** in order to find the correlation between the discount changes and the sales groth correlation.

In Machine Learning, we seldom compare two percentage data, instead, we compare the actual sales/discount value. A simple ML can be applied by Linear regression (most ML is used in multi-dimension, as your case is one-x one-y data (single column to single output). Please refer to related information online and solved with excel or python code.